# Taking screenshot of a layout having large size images in ImageViews in android

Tags: java, android

i load images from camera and gallery  in ImageViews in a layout and i have to take screenshots of that layout, if i have small size images i can capture screenshot successfully but if i load large size images from gallery my code throws a null pointer exception
( can some one help me sorting it out)

i have following code

```
try{  
     im2 =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_backgroundImage1);
   }catch(Exception ex){
     int a;
     int b;
     a = 11;
     b = 12;
   }
            View v1 = im2;






            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            v1.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            v1.layout(0, 0, v1.getMeasuredWidth(), v1.getMeasuredHeight());
            v1.buildDrawingCache(true);
            bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);




            //saving

            String date = (DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date()).toString());
            //save_path is used to pick image to be sent via email
            save_path ="/sdcard/Collages" + File.separator + date + ".PNG";

             f = new File(save_path);                     
            try {
             f.createNewFile();
            // write the bytes in file
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
            }catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
              }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Saved at " + f.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Post your exception stack as well

Comment: 10-06 21:03:41.967: W/View(9245): View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs 4981984 bytes, only 3686400 available

Comment: Sounds like the view is too large to fit into the drawing cache. You should down sample the image, http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @SadeelAnjum it doesn't say anything - post the complete exception in your post that also shows which line has the problem